# Надо в css выравнять картинку svg

Tags: html, css

[image]

svg растянулось на полстраницы, как его поставить в правый верхний угол, с таким же размером логотипа?

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.logo{
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    align: top;
}
.container{
    width: 1536px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.telephone1{
    font: 16pt 'Times';
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.telephone2{
    font: 16pt 'Times';
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.header{
    height: 155px;
    background-color: rgb(51, 74, 113);
    position: relative;
}
.meb{
    font: 18pt 'Times';
    color: white;
    float: left;
}
.info{
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 350px;
}
.linfo{
    right: 110px;
    color: white;
    font: 18pt 'Times';
}
.city{
    text-align: center;
}
.button{
    background-color: rgb(53, 53, 255);
    border: none;
    font: 16pt 'Times';
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.pagination{
    padding-left: 200px;
    padding-right: 200px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.but{
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.button:hover{
    background-color: rgb(116, 116, 255);
}
.linktext{
    font: 16pt 'Times';
    color: rgb(255, 255, 118);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Багет-сервис|главная</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.svg" class='logo' alt="logo"></a>
            <p class="meb">Мебельные фасады</p>
            <ul class="info">
                <div>
                    <li class="linfo telephone1">8(861)257-06-87</li>
                </div>
                <li class="linfo telephone2">8(800)500-10-61</li>
                <li class="linfo city">г.Краснодар</li>
                <li class="linfo but"><button class='button' href='#'> Как начать сотрудничество </button></li>
                <a href="#" class='linktext dostavka'>Доставка</a>
                <a href="#" class="linktext contacts">Контакты</a>
                <a href="#" class="linktext wherebuy">Где купить</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Приложите код, пожалуйста. Но сразу могу сказать что проблема в самом svg, его нужно обрезать, а то большие отступы, особенно сверху и снизу

Comment: Добавил код уже